# SED file location is wrong when generate exe using IExpress.exe

Tags: c#, exe, self-extracting, iexpress

I have a project to generate bundled exe using IExpress.exe and run the following command from command prompt

```
iexpress /n "C:\Users\Desktop\Generation\template.sed"
```

which invokes the IExpress UI and pasted automatically with incorrect value in the text box for SED location

Incorrect path: **C:\WINDOWS\system32"C:\Users\Desktop\Generation\template.sed"**

i am wondering why this discrepant. Could any one provide suggestions to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Use /t option : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-ieak/iexpress-command-line-options

Comment: @jdweng The command is used to specify the path for extraction. but my question is how to generate the exe with sed file & sed file path is getting wrong when try the iexpress command from cmd prompt.

Comment: did you try the /toption?  When you use the /t you will not get the C:\WINDOWS\system32 as part of the path.

Comment: It is not working and got incorrect command error. The option you mentioned is to control your Internet Explorer custom browser package extraction process. But here i need is to generate the cab/exe file. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You may need to use more than one option.  You need to use the /t to resolve the path issue.  Now you are getting a different error.